# Available plans to create the Tone Analyzer service in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I tried to create the Tone Analyzer service in IBM Cloud using

```
cf create-service tone_analyzer beta rtt-tone-analyzer
```

but I  got "Could not find plan with name beta".
What is the correct cf command or service plan?

Answer (score 2):

You can find information about the [Tone Analyzer in the IBM Cloud Catalog](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/tone-analyzer). There is a Lite, Standard and Premium plan available. Those plans can be specified in the `create-service` command.

As an alternative, you could use the inofficial tool [mycatalog](http://mycatalog.mybluemix.net/), select the Tone Analyzer service, click on the CLI link. It brings up the possible CLI commands to create the different services. Here is the syntax for the free Lite plan.

```
ibmcloud cf create-service tone-analyzer lite <service-name>
```

Because most services are IAM-controlled, the Cloud Foundry-related syntax above should be replaced with the general resource command:

```
ibmcloud resource service-instance-create <service-name> tone-analyzer lite <region>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this option unfortunately  without success:
1.cf create  Tone Analyzer-ss tone-analyzer lite Dallas
2.cf create  tone-analyzer lite Dallas
3.ibmcloud resource service-instance-create Tone Analyzer-ss tone-analyzer lite Dallas
what I did wrong? thanks

Comment: What about `ibmcloud resource service-instance-create Tone-Analyzer-ss tone-analyzer lite us-south`?

Comment: maybe I did  something wrong, I  opened the cmd type:
C:\Projects\moods>cf create-service Tone-Analyzer-ss tone-analyzer lite us-south
FAILED
C:\Projects\moods>ibmcloud resource service-instance-create Tone-Analyzer-ss tone-analyzer lite us-south but is still not work

Comment: I already installed  the IBM Cloud Cli, and I used the regular cmd of windows,
I fill little silly but there are unique cmd for  IBM Cloud Cli? if the answer is yes,
please tell me where I can find it? thank you so much

Comment: Using the CLI is a different question / discussion. Let's clean up the comments and if there is need, open questions on using the CLI on Windows.

Comment: finally I  succeed to enter the ibmcloud login command, thanks to you.
now I  got the message after entering the email,etc...
- Use 'ibmcloud target --cf' to target Cloud Foundry org/space interactively, or use 'ibmcloud target --cf-api ENDPOINT -o ORG -s SPACE' to target the org/space. so  I  searched and find the format:ibmcloud target [-r REGION_NAME] [-c ACCOUNT_ID] [-g RESOURCE_GROUP] [--cf] [-o ORG] [-s SPACE], so  I enter ibmcloud target - Dallas-c 1770253-g Default--cf-o lior2-s lior2, there somthing wrong with my format?